# WinForms - How to set up a "subscription" to non-modal form events?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a database driven, multi-user vb.net WinForms application which presents the user with a calendar/scheduling interface.  Users may edit multiple appointments on the calendar at the same time and thus have one, many or no instances of the "Edit Appointment" form open.

In other places in the application I have various search features which may display lists of events - including those which may currently be being edited.  If one of these events were edited, moved, or deleted, the search table would be stale.

When I open my search feature, I would like to be able to "subscribe" to events generated by all open "Edit Appointment" forms.  Then, if an appointment displayed in the search interface is modified/deleted, the search table an refresh itself.

Is there some best practice or mechanism in vb.net to enable this?

Specific Concerns:

- I need a way to list or keep track of all open "Edit Appointment" forms
- Additional "Edit Appointment" forms may be opened while the search interface is already open.
- If my search interface closes, I will need to un-subscribe to these visual basic events so I don't have a memory leak or unexpected behavior.

**Clarification**: I am thinking that the proper way to handle this is by handling the "FormClosed" or a generated event from the "Edit Appointment" form.  This visual basic event would need be "handled" in some way so it could notify subscribing forms that a change has (potentially) occured.

Comment: Rather than a form-centric app, consider Classes

Comment: I'm not sure what that means in this context.  My understanding is that all forms are classes.  In what way could I use classes to solve my problem?

Comment: Yes all forms are classes - *their* specialty is interacting with the user.  Rather than something (you did not mention what) subscribing to various form events to Do Something, an Appointment Class could contain the data and the logic to act on it. It could then tell Form87 to change "foo" to "bar" if that is needed.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you are using the term "event" in your post to refer to both a calendar event (like a meeting that can be canceled) and a class Event that invokes some code action.  This makes it difficult to discern your goal.  If this is correct, can you edit your post to clarify this?

Comment: I am referring to an "Event" in the Visual Basic "AddHandler"/"RemoveHandler"/"WithEvents" sense.

I tried to be really specific when referring to something as an appointment as opposed to an event.

The idea is that when my "Edit Appointment" form closes it would emit an Event which could be captured by another form.  The issue is that that there can be multiple "Edit Appointment" forms so I can't just define them as "WithEvents".  I could the forms to a collection and add handlers to them as they are created, but that seems like there is a lot of potential for unhandled events.

Comment: See your 2nd paragraph, `I have various search features which may display lists of events - including those which may currently be being edited`.  This is what I found confusing.  But anyway, see if any of the answers will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many who code only in VB never realize that Events are just a syntactic sugar coating for managing and invoking a delegate. If you were to declare a [VB Custom Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt1k2w4e.aspx), this concept become obvious.

With that said, one possible solution, is to just pass a callback delegate to the EditAppointment form that is invoked on form closure instead of using the typical Event-subscription model.

```
Public Class EditAppointment : Inherits Form
    Public Delegate Sub OnCloseCallBack(ea As EditAppointment)
    Private callBack As OnCloseCallBack
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(onCloseCallBackMethod As OnCloseCallBack)
        Me.New()
        Me.callBack = onCloseCallBackMethod
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnClosed(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnClosed(e)
        callBack.Invoke(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then an example usage could be:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ea As New EditAppointment(AddressOf EditAppointmentClosed)
        ea.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub EditAppointmentClosed(ea As EditAppointment)
        ' do something on EditAppointment closed
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is brilliant.  I see how I can use this precisely.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The way I handle this in C#/WPF is to have put an event on my edit form like so:

```
    public event EventHandler<AppointmentSavedEventArgs> AppointmentSavedEvent;
```

When the item is saved I check for subscribers to the event and fire if needed:

```
                    if (this.AppointmentSavedEvent != null)
                    {
                        this.AppointmentSavedEvent(this, new AppointmentSavedEventArgs(theAppointment.AppointmentID));
                    }
```

In my case my "search" or "List" has a button that opens the edit screen.  When I open the edit screen I attach the Saved event.

```
            // Note this is a user control shown using a generic window manager... don't get hung up on that part
            ucAppointmentEdit ucAE = new ucAppointmentEdit(((Appointment)(dataGrid.SelectedItem)));
            ucce.AppointmentSavedEvent += ucAE_AppointmentSavedEvent;
```

So when I catch the saved event I just refresh the list...

If you have multiple screens that kick off the edit part, you may need to think about looping through to find any "List" or "search" windows that need to be updated.

Sorry didn't have time to convert to Winforms, but this should get ya going... (if I understood your question correctly)

Comment: This seems really interesting, but I just can't make the translation from C# to VB.NET.  I don't understand what you're actually doing.